# Alternative for Table element in Ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I use to use **tables** to create layout when I'm creating contents with Ckeditor.

For instance to make a 3 column layout. Then I could insert texts, image and so on in each column.

My question is: can I create this kind of layout in other way, I mean: not using **tables**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `div element` with CSS style in mode `HTML` of CKEDITOR.

If you need an other feature, write a plugin ;)

Comment: I'd be interested in writing a plugin to let me choose: 2 columns layour and 3 columns layout. Can I do this? Any link to a tutorial for total beginner out there?